# Redirect output of a program to a file fails

Tags: io-redirection

So I have a program lets call it foo.
I am attempting to redirect its terminal output to a file using the following command.

```
foo > ./someFile.txt
```

Now when I run that command someFile.txt gets created however it is empty. Any suggestions on how I could redirect the terminal output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is expected behavior, that a file `someFile.txt` will be created. Whether or not this file contains anything, depends on what your program `foo` is supposed to do.

Whatever problem you are encountering, does not seem to be related to output redirection. You can try following command as a test:

```
cat > someFile.txt
```

type anything. Whatever you typed will be redirected to `someFile.txt` (end with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>).

Bytheway, the output file is being created by your shell, not by your program `foo`. Even if you type a nonexistent command, the output file will still be created (empty):

```
/bin/nonexistent > zzz
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is that `foo` uses `isatty` and doesn't write anything to stdout if stdout does not point somewhere interactive.

> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
> #include <unistd.h>
> int isatty(int fd);
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>          The isatty() function tests whether fd is an open file descriptor referring to a terminal.

This short Python program demonstrates it:

```
import sys, os

if sys.stdout.isatty():
    print "Hello, tty %s" % os.ttyname(1)
else:
    print "stdout: not a typewriter: how boring"
```

As does this short C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (void) {
    if ( isatty(stdout) ) {
        printf("Hello, tty %s\n", ttyname(1));
    } else {
        printf("stdout: not a typewriter: how boring\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Both programs have the identical behaviour:

```
$ ./isatty > notatty ; cat notatty
stdout: not a typewriter: how boring

$ ./isatty.py
Hello, tty /dev/pts/1

$ ./isatty | cat
stdout: not a typewriter: how boring
```

Programs can choose how, what and whether or not they print based on whether they are being redirected.

A common application of this is to avoid writing ANSI escape sequences read by terminals (`\e[33;1m`, etc) for text colouring to files, which looks ugly and confuses parsers.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. My program log was not written to [stdout] as expected, but to [stderr] instead. A redirection of both [stdout] and [stderr] was therefore the solution:

```
foo >> someFile.txt 2>&1
```